# Network interface for raw sockets in python?

Tags: python, raw-sockets

I'm writing a small configuration utility for a wireless bridge in Python, using raw sockets with Ethernet II proto 0x8888. There are several tutorials on raw sockets for python, but all of them seem to hardcode the network interface ("eth0", "eth1", etc.), which I don't want to, because each computer might have a different network interface (on my laptop its "wlan0").

My current working code is (unfortunatly with hardcoded "wlan0"):

```
# Create an Ethernet II broadcast of ethertype 0x8888:
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_PACKET, socket.SOCK_RAW, 0x8888)
s.bind(("wlan0",0x8888))
ifName,ifProto,pktType,hwType,hwAddr = s.getsockname()
txFrame = struct.pack("!6s6sH","\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF",hwAddr,0x8888) + "\x00"*0x32
# Send and wait for response
s.send(txFrame)
```

Is there any way to get the network interface name on the current system instead of having to hardcode it?

I have tried INADDR_ANY, but that doesn't work either.

Comment: The third parameter to the `socket` function is the protocol type, it shouldn't be `0x8888`, but an "IEEE  802.3  protocol number in network order" (see http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man7/packet.7.html)

Comment: Most computers have several different interfaces.  My laptop has 5, for example: eth6, wlan0, lo, tunl0, sit0.  How will you distinguish between them for your purposes?

Comment: The protocol I'm using is really a raw Ethernet II protocol with protocol ID 0x8888 (it is NOT an IP protocol!), so the third argument to socket is correct. A reverse-engineered description of the protocol is at: http://wiki.kainhofer.com/hardware/vap11g_wlan_bridge

Comment: @Elf: I'm trying to send out a broadcast to detect all responding devices on the network. So, I would be fine if I could send to all interfaces (I have five interfaces too: eth0, wlan0, lo, ppp0, tun0). It would also suffice to get a list of all available interfaces, so I would create a raw socket for each of them.

Comment: @ReinholdKainhofer - Do you just need a list of all interfaces? The answer below should work for linux.

Comment: @ReinholdKainhofer -Has this question been satisfactorily answered or do you still require an answer?

Answer (score 0):

You can use subprocess and re to get a list of the network interfaces:

```
import subprocess, re

config = subprocess.check_output("ifconfig")
expr = re.compile("([a-zA-Z0-9]+)\s+Link")
interfaces = expr.findall(config)
```

ifconfig also has options that allow you to see 'down' interfaces although I don't think you'll need them if you want to broadcast. See `man ifconfig` for more details.